# Как тестировать angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma

Проект ionic, установил Karma в корне сделал init

```
karma init karma.conf.js
```

сделал папку tests, там файл test.js с содержимым

```
describe('Places service', function() {
    it('returns particular place', function() {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

Проект лежит в www

```
project folder
 tests
 www
   lib
     angular
         angular.js
```

Прописал в конфиг

```
files: [
        'www/lib/angular/angular.js'
        'tests/*.js'
    ],
```

С файлом теста не запускается karma когда его убираю запускается.

Не могу понять как запустить.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то ошибки в терминале?

Comment: Пробовал это на работе на ubuntu, пришёл домой вроде все работает, так же делал, сейчас разбираюсь как рест  замокать